# Cannot get ldap_modify to work

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to use [LDAP user password change code](https://gist.github.com/mattrude/657334) but I have stuck on a step where `ldap_modify` throwing LDAP error:

> 1 - Operations error

First I thought that password encryption method is not correct but even code

```
  $rootdn = "cn=ldap_manager,dc=mycompany,dc=local";
  $rootpwd = "mysecretkeys";
  $r = ldap_bind($con,$rootdn,$rootpwd);

  $entry = array();
  $entry["givenName"] = "BabaGanush";

    if ($r = ldap_modify($con,$user_dn,$entry) === false){   
    $error = ldap_error($con);
    $errno = ldap_errno($con);
    $message[] = "E201 - Please contact the administrator.";
    $message[] = "$errno - $error";
  } else {
    $message[] = "Name was changed";
  }
```

is not working (getting the same Error #1).

I have tried all possible combinations for rootDN but cannot get bind when used `ldap_manager`

```
  $rootdn = "CN=users,DC=mycompany,DC=local";

  $username = 'ldap_mamanger';
  $domain = 'mycompany';

  $rootdn = $username;
  $rootdn = $username.'@'.$domain;
  $rootdn = $domain.'\\'.$username;
  $rootdn = "uid=$username,cn=users,dc=$domain,dc=local";
  $rootdn = "uid=$username,dc=$domain,dc=local";
  $rootdn = "uid=$username,dc=local";
  $rootdn = "uid=$username,dc=$domain";
```

when `$ldaprdn = $domain.'\\'.$username;` works fine for regular AD user (can bind)

`dsquery user -name ldap*` returns

> "CN=ldap_manager,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local"
>   "CN=ldap_user,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local"

Any clue what can be wrong?

Comment: you have sufficient privileges in AD to modify records?

Comment: @RamRaider Yes - I do. When I look on my code I'm not sure about `$rootdn` value if this is correct

Comment: use `dsquery` to quickly find the proper root dn

Comment: @RamRaider OK - did `dsquery user -name ldap*`and got `"CN=ldap_manager,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local"
"CN=ldap_user,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local"`

Comment: looks a bit different to what you posted - have you tried using the known rootDN?

Comment: Yes and can't bind at all. Then I have tested reg user and I'm able to bind so no clue why not for rootDN

Comment: As far as I know, modifying the password with AD requires that the connection is secured by SSL.

Comment: @LudovicPoitou Indeed http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Setting%20and%20Changing%20Microsoft%20Active%20Directory%20Passwords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see it, you are trying to modify a complete **entry**. That means, `ldap_modify` replaces the current content located under the given DN with the new content. And I'm sure there are some fields that are left empty shich are required when you replace the current entry with one that contains **only** a givenName.

So either fetch the current entry and replace the value in question within that result or you might want to have a look at `ldap_mod_replace`.

Comment: Switched to `ldap_mod_replace`. Now I can bind with `ldap_manager` but final outcome is an error: `53 - Server is unwilling to perform` which is not related to my question. Anyway I'm closer to get this nailed than before.